# Why is the runtime of a bitwise operation constant?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

Let's say we are performing a XOR operation over an integer 1 and 4 to find the Hamming Distance. Why is the runtime of XOR and other bitwise operations below constant? Is it because the size of int is fixed in langauges like Python and etc., that's why the operation will take consant time regardless of integer inputs?

[Edit]
Let's say we are calculating the hamming distance of two integers using Brian Kernighan's Algorithm as below.

`def hammingDistance(x: int, y: int):
        xor = x ^ y
        distance = 0
        while xor:
            distance += 1
            # remove the rightmost bit of '1'
            xor = xor & (xor - 1)
        return distance`

Comment: Could be because this operation is performed with hardware, like every mathematical and logical operations

Comment: You can't answer any running-time questions without first identifying what the input size is.

Comment: 0 ≤ x, y < 2^31

Answer (score 1):

That *function* is not constant-time (it depends on what the highest set bit is), but each *bitwise operator* in it is constant-time on most (or all?) modern CPUs, which have instructions for those that operate on entire 16/32/64-bit operands in a fixed number of cycles.

Bitwise instructions are some of the simplest CPU instructions; I'd be curious to know if any processor ever had variable-time bit manipulation instructions. There are very few arithmetic CPU instructions that have runtimes that depend on their values. Some examples are division (in some/most? cases), multiplication when denormals are involved and `pdep` on current AMD CPUs.

Comment: Since we know that the largest int is 2^31, so the maximum bit length's threshold of 2^31 is 32, given `bin(2**31).replace('0b','') = '10000000000000000000000000000000'`. So, we can assume that the function runs in constant time complexity. I am sorry that I left out the input size.